# Aggregate data.frame for each day

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a data.frame `dat` about car sells (`Buy=0` in the data frame) and buys (`Buy=1` in the data frame) of a used car seller.

```
  Date       Buy   Price
29-06-2015    1    5000
29-06-2015    0    8000
29-06-2015    1    10000
30-06-2015    0    3500
30-06-2015    0    12000 
...          ...  ...
```

What I need is a new, aggregated data.frame that gives me the number of buys and the number of sells per day together with the summed prices of all the buys and sells for that day:

```
  Date      Buys   Sells   Price_Buys  Price_Sells
29-06-2015    2    1         15000        8000
30-06-2015    0    2           0          15500
...          ...  ...
```

I tried to use `aggregate(dat$Buy, by=list(Date=dat$Date, FUN=sum))`. However, I am still struggling how to aggregate the sells as well.

Comment: I don't see any information on sales in your original data set.

Comment: @Stibu I think zero in `Buy` column means "sale", and one means "buy".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done pretty cleanly in `dplyr`, grouping by date using `group_by` and then summarizing with `summarize`:

```
library(dplyr)
(out <- dat %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarize(Buys=sum(Buy == 1), Sells=sum(Buy == 0),
            Price_Buys=sum(Price[Buy == 1]), Price_Sells=sum(Price[Buy == 0])))
#         Date  Buys Sells Price_Buys Price_Sells
#       (fctr) (int) (int)      (int)       (int)
# 1 29-06-2015     2     1      15000        8000
# 2 30-06-2015     0     2          0       15500
```

You can now manipulate this object as you would a normal data frame, e.g. with something like:

```
out$newvar <- with(out, Sells*Price_Sells - Buys*Price_Buys)
out
# Source: local data frame [2 x 6]
#         Date  Buys Sells Price_Buys Price_Sells newvar
#       (fctr) (int) (int)      (int)       (int)  (int)
# 1 29-06-2015     2     1      15000        8000 -22000
# 2 30-06-2015     0     2          0       15500  31000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. One more question: How can I address the columns of the new local data frame, e.g. to calculate a new column with the revenue per day (Sells x Price_Sells - Buys x Price_Buys)?

Comment: @jeffrey I've updated the answer to show how to add new variables.

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` V 1.9.6+ you can now provide a list of functions to the `fun` argument, so we can easily solve this with `dcast` (*without specifying any conditions by hand*)

```
library(data.table) # V1.9.6+
dcast(setDT(dat), Date ~ Buy , value.var = "Price", fun = list(length, sum))
#          Date Price_length_0 Price_length_1 Price_sum_0 Price_sum_1
# 1: 29-06-2015              1              2        8000       15000
# 2: 30-06-2015              2              0       15500           0
```

---

Or if we want to to try `dplyr`, a robust way of solving this (*again, without specifying any conditions*) could be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Date, Buy) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum, length), Price)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
# Groups: Date [?]
# 
#         Date   Buy   sum length
#       (fctr) (int) (int)  (int)
# 1 29-06-2015     0  8000      1
# 2 29-06-2015     1 15000      2
# 3 30-06-2015     0 15500      2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use library `dplyr` to do this:

```
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(buys = sum(Buy == 1), sells = sum(Buy == 0), Price_Buys = sum(Price[Buy == 1]), Price_Sells = sum(Price[Buy == 0]))
Source: local data frame [2 x 5]

        Date  buys sells Price_Buys Price_Sells
      (fctr) (int) (int)      (int)       (int)
1 29-06-2015     2     1      15000        8000
2 30-06-2015     0     2          0       15500
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use one of the `dpylr` solutions myself, but I think it is still noteworthy, that it can also be done with `aggregate()`, since this is how you started out:

```
aggregate(cbind(Buys = Buy, Sells = !Buy,
                Price_Buys = Price * Buy, Price_Sells = Price * !Buy) ~ Date,
          data = dat, sum)
##         Date Buys Sells Price_Buys Price_Sells
## 1 29-06-2015    2     1      15000        8000
## 2 30-06-2015    0     2          0       15500
```

The idea here is to get the sales as `!Buy`. This will convert `Buy` to a logical (0 => `TRUE`, 1 => `FALSE`) and then apply the NOT-operator (!) to it. In this way, 0 is converted to 1 and 1 is converted to 0. The same trick can be used when calculating the price.

The comparison of this solution to the others should also show you, that `dplyr` produces much more readable code.